# getting li title="info" with document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, jira

I have `<div>..` as follows:

```
<div id="customfield_16332_nfeed_component"> 
  <ul class="text token-input-list-facebook"> 
    <li title="Firm Name(Summ.)" class="token-input-token-facebook"> 
      <p>Firm Name(Details)...</p> 
      <span class="token-input-delete-token-facebook">×</span> 
    </li> 
    <li class="token-input-input-token-facebook"></li> 
  </ul> 
  <input type="text" style="border: 0px; padding: 0px; display: none; "/> 
</div>
```

My goal is getting `Firm Name(Summ.)` in this `div` with JavaScript.
My JavaScript Code:

```
var summ = document.getElementById("summary"); 
summ.onfocus=function(){ 
    var adsoyad= document.getElementById('customfield_16332_nfeed_component').getElementsByTagName('li'); 
    document.getElementById("summary").value = adsoyad; 
}
```

But, I didn't get with

```
document.getElementById('customfield_16332_nfeed_component').getElementsByTagName('li')
```

How can I use `document.getElementById`?

Answer (score 1):

Get the title from first `li`

```
var adsoyad= document.getElementById('customfield_16332_nfeed_component');
adsoyad = adsoyad.getElementsByTagName('li');
adsoyad = adsoyad[0].getAttribute("title");
```